# game maker studio:i broke the controls of my player

Tags: scripting, game-maker, arrow-keys

i cannot get my code to work,
i followed a tutorial closely then proof read my work.
it worked for the teacher but when i tried it my player was stuck, 
it didn't animate or move.
i split the code up into different parts as that is what was in the tutorial.

here is the main bit :

```
///script_get_input
right_key = keyboard_check(vk_right);
up_key = keyboard_check(vk_up);
left_key = keyboard_check(vk_left)
down_key = keyboard_check(vk_down)
dash_key = keyboard_check_pressed(ord('C'));
attack_key = keyboard_check(ord('X'));

///check for gamepad input
if (gamepad_is_connected(0)) {
    right_key = (gamepad_axis_value( 0, gp_axislh)>= .5);
    left_key = (gamepad_axis_value( 0, gp_axislh)>= -.5);
    up_key = (gamepad_axis_value( 0, gp_axislv)>= -.5);
    down_key = (gamepad_axis_value( 0, gp_axislv)>= .5)

}
```

and that sets the controls while this sets what they do :

```
    ///scr_move_state
scr_get_input();

///get the axis
var xaxis = (right_key - left_key);
var yaxis = (down_key - up_key);

///get direction
dir = point_direction(0, 0, xaxis, yaxis);

///get length
if (xaxis == 0 and yaxis = 0) {
    len = 0;
} else {
     len = spd;
}
///get the hspd and vspd
hspd = lengthdir_x(len, dir);
vspd = lengthdir_y(len, dir);

///move
phy_position_x += hspd;
phy_position_y += vspd;

///control the sprite
image_speed = sign(len)*.2;
if (len == 0) image_index = 0;

///vertical sprites
if (vspd > 0) { 
    sprite_index = spr_player_down;
} else if (vspd < 0) {
    sprite_index = spr_player_up;
}

///horizontal sprites
if (hspd > 0) {
    spr_index = spr_player_right;
} else if (hspd < 0) {
    sprite_index = spr_player_left;
}
```

oh and also how the player interacts with the code

```
///moves the player in the step event
scr_get_input();
script_execute(state);
```

it looks really complex and i am just a beginner to coding languages.
also i heard that game maker has a unique language making it more difficult.
any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird tutorial. Care to share it?

First of all, you're using the `phy_position_*` variables, this requires your object to be a physics one. Is the object a physics object? Is the physiscs world inialized in your room?

Your code in general looks fine. Allthough; `script_execute(state);` looks weird. Do you have a script called state? If so, what are those contents, and why not just run it like `state()`?